# What is O(n) difficulty of the function which search for elements of list which starts from certain prefix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the following code, the code is supposed to find all elemets in list which starts with certain prefix, the interviewer asked what O() difficulty has the code, I answered O(n), where n is number of elements in list, it seems to me that it was wrong answer since recruiter was very dissapointed. What is the right answer and why?

```py
def count_elemets(list_elements, prefix):
    result = []
    for i in list_elements:
        if i.startswith(prefix):
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

What is the right answer and why?

Comment: looks like `O(n)` to me too...

Comment: O(n) startswith operations, but startswith isn't constant time.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre♦ From my point of view I can't say what is real difficulty of the process since it depends on number of elements which I add to result (since list grow 2 times in some moments), I do not know complexity of startwith and append , since I do not know how the methods was written. So it's very tricky question, especially if to count that I am searching for my first developer job.

Comment: for instance `append` is `O(1)` except when the capacity is exceeded and `realloc` has to move the elements somewhere else: At this point it's `O(n)` but depends on the implementation.

Comment: @user2357112 How is `startswith` not constant time ?

Comment: @user2357112 I guess that startwith probably have O(n) complexity where n in number of characters in prefix string, but again I  have no idea how the method was written in Python

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre♦ it is not my worst interview, this Monday I had interview in another company,  after I was able to answer some Python questions, I was asked to write http server in Go or Java, neither of the languages was in my CV and I am looking for Python Jr developer job, I was also said that they need developer who can code in Python, PHP, C, C++, Java, Rust simultaneously, after all the interviews I feel myself really dumb.

Comment: they should not expect that you know 5 languages (which are pretty different) as a junior. Don't let that stop you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken a look to the implementation of the `startswith` function.

There are some points to consider. First of all the for loop is O(n) and the number of matched characters (let's say k), makes the complexity O(k*n) (can still be considered O(n)).

Another point is, that it seems the `startswith` function, can take a `tuple` as a prefix parameter, if any of the prefixes in the tuple is present (startswith that prefix), it is returned `True`. So one could also argue that the size of the prefix tuple is also relevant.

But still, these can all be considered O(n), I don't know if your interviewer asked for a more specific answer, but I think he should have better explained what exactly is required from you in the answer.

Here is the implementation if you want to take a look.

```
static PyObject *
unicode_startswith(PyObject *self,
                   PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *subobj;
    PyObject *substring;
    Py_ssize_t start = 0;
    Py_ssize_t end = PY_SSIZE_T_MAX;
    int result;

    if (!stringlib_parse_args_finds("startswith", args, &subobj, &start, &end))
        return NULL;
    if (PyTuple_Check(subobj)) {
        Py_ssize_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < PyTuple_GET_SIZE(subobj); i++) {
            substring = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(subobj, i);
            if (!PyUnicode_Check(substring)) {
                PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                             "tuple for startswith must only contain str, "
                             "not %.100s",
                             Py_TYPE(substring)->tp_name);
                return NULL;
            }
            result = tailmatch(self, substring, start, end, -1);
            if (result == -1)
                return NULL;
            if (result) {
                Py_RETURN_TRUE;
            }
        }
        /* nothing matched */
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    if (!PyUnicode_Check(subobj)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "startswith first arg must be str or "
                     "a tuple of str, not %.100s", Py_TYPE(subobj)->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    result = tailmatch(self, subobj, start, end, -1);
    if (result == -1)
        return NULL;
    return PyBool_FromLong(result);
}
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c

Comment: Maybe they wanted them to say O(n^2)? Because technically `startswith` includes a loop, so it's a nested loop.

Comment: @NickVitha It depends on how the function is called. If the function is called with a single string as prefix, the loop is never entered.

Comment: that is true. Maybe the interviewer assumed startswith was O(n) though.

Comment: @NickVitha actually it was screening skype interview for Python Jr position and lasted only 4 min 15 seconds, the time I spent on reading of 8 lines 12px text, writing the 6 lines of code in google doc file and answering the question about complexity, so I can't imagine what was expected. Probably the rightest answer in O(n*m*k) where n - number of elements in list, m - number of append operations with memory double and k is a numbers of characters in prefix.

Comment: Yeah, O(nmk) might be the *most exact* answer, but that goes against the entire point of using O() notation. 

The interviewer definitely should have told/asked you "Hey, what about startswith" or something. 

Also, the fact it was a 5 minute interview seems very confusing.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev no, do not factor in the append operations, append is amortized constant time. O(n*k) is probably the closest, where `n` is the the length of the input list, and k is the length of the prefix.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sounds reasonable, afterall it seems to be very tricky question